# CSS3 animated text. Stop a content end

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to stop the border based cursor at the end of the animated text instead of going to the edge of the window. I've tried setting the width of the container and adjusting the text width, but this is going to be used with variables of undetermined width.

```
<div class="type">
    <h1>We have some basic text here</h1>
</div>


body { background: #333; font-family: "Lato"; color: #fff; }

div.type {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.type h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .05em solid #aaa;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation:
    type 5s steps(100, end)
}

@keyframes type {
  from { width: 0; }
  to { width: 100%; }
}
```

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/probie12/pen/GOxMLG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using max-width instead of width.

```
.type h1 {
  display: inline-block; <-- added
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: .05em solid #aaa;
  max-width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation:
    type 5s steps(100, end)
}

@keyframes type {
  from { max-width: 0; }
  to { max-width: 100%; }
}
```

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqxgwy)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I also learned that the CSS3 animation isn't allowing more than one call to be made to the same dom element. Personally I think this causes more markup than needed. Just a note for others looking at this. Thanks for the solution.